# Error when displaying the CiviCRM Menu

Tags: core, stripe

As an admin, when I want to display the CiviCRM Menu instead of the drupal menu (via .../civicrm/dashboard), I often get the following Error Message :

*Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using "Stripe::setApiKey()". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.*

Then, if I insist, just once, I get to the Civi dashboard page with the civicrm Menu and there is no more message, and every-thing works correctly.

Apart from this, I have no problem with payments via Stripe.

CiviCRM 5.13.2 / Drupal 7.67

Comment: what do you mean by "when I want to display the CiviCRM Menu" - do you mean when you want to edit the civicrm navigation menu? or do you mean when you go to a civicrm path?

Comment: I mean : as an admin, I can choose to display either the Drupal menu or the CiviCRM menu ; when I move to the CiviCRM Menu (via dashboard), I get this message. Could this be a time-out problem in the Stripe extension ?

Comment: Still not certain i am following. which feature are you using to show/hide the menu? In civi there is a 'hide menu' option. I just enabled Stripe on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1 but i didn't complete setting up a payment processor with it. maybe you could (a test one) and clarify what you are doing on your site and compare with dmaster to help identify the issue?

Comment: also not clear if you are hiding menu while in Drupal or in civicrm

Comment: When the Menu is hidden (in my configuration, hiding the Menu displays the Drupal Menu), you can display the Civicrm Menu via .../civicrm/dashboard : this is where the problem occurs (I have just edited the question accordingly). I could not reproduce the problem on the demo site, where this works fine.

Comment: What version of the Stripe extension? Possibly related to this? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31700/random-stripe-webhook-issues

Comment: Good question : I used Stripe Extension version 5.3.2 ; I have just updated to 5.4.1 : I hope it fixes : I wait and see.

Answer (score 3):

This was due to an unused Payment Processor which had no API key.
Deleting this Payment Processor fixed the issue.