# Random Stripe Webhook Issues

Tags: payment-processor, stripe

Latest CiviCRM - Latest Stripe - Wordpress

I am getting this error often:

```
Stripe Payment Processor Webhook: Credit Card (3)
Stripe Payment Processor Webhook: Credit Card (4)
```

From what I can tell - our stripe webhook is correctly setup.

Answer (score 5):

I think the new version tries to create the webhook automatically. Maybe if it already exists in the Stripe account it can't create it -- have you tried deleting the webhooks in the Stripe account and then using the "Fix Stripe Webhook" (**civicrm/stripe/fix-webhook**) page in CiviCRM to regenerate it?

Comment: This is correct.  You can ignore the erors or delete/regenerate.  Per the extension author, webhooks should have an API version associated with them - but when I created them manually, they didn't.  The lack of API version is what it's complaining about.