# How to fix stripe webhook settings?

Tags: payment-processor, stripe, settings

I am on civi 5.16.3, drupal 7.X and stripe 5.4.1
and when setting up stripe webhook, keep receiving this message. how can I fix it please? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would follow the instructions on screen:

- Log in to your Stripe account, go to the Webhooks section
- Delete the existing webhook (on live and testing sides)
- Come back to CiviCRM and use the "Update/Create Webhook" button

Comment: See also: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31701/26

Answer (score 2):

If you think the webhook URL is correct and the extension is still printing the error message on the status page and the same is also not getting fixed by `Fix Stripe Webhook`, make sure -

- You have correct latest API version set for your webhook.
- Only a bunch of events are enabled for triggering the webhook instead of "All Events". The events currently supported by the extension is -

  1. invoice.payment_succeeded
  2. invoice.payment_failed
  3. charge.failed
  4. charge.refunded
  5. charge.succeeded
  6. customer.subscription.updated
  7. customer.subscription.deleted